# cloudinary java not able to upload image

Tags: java, cloudinary

my code is below.I try to upload image into cloudinary through java but not uploaded it shows the below error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnknownError: Can't find
>   Cloudinary platform adapter 
>   [com.cloudinary.android.UploaderStrategy,com.cloudinary.http42.UploaderStrategy,com.cloudinary.http43.UploaderStrategy]
>     at com.cloudinary.Cloudinary.loadStrategies(Cloudinary.java:76)     at
>   com.cloudinary.Cloudinary.(Cloudinary.java:91)  at
>   ImageUpload.main(ImageUpload.java:16)

my code is following

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.cloudinary.Cloudinary;
import com.cloudinary.utils.ObjectUtils;

public class ImageUpload {
    public static void main(String arg[])throws Exception{

        Map config = ObjectUtils.asMap(
                  "cloud_name", "dq8rshzka",
                  "api_key", "484362882976754",
                  "api_secret", "1zwPe6-VfVjj3rueX6zSsfyNyro");
                Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
                Map result = cloudinary.api().resource("sample", ObjectUtils.emptyMap());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please open a support ticket and Cloudinary's support team will be happy to assist. Regardless, please note that your account's `api_secret` should never be revealed. You should go to your account's settings page and generate a new pair of api key and secret.

Answer (score 3):

Try add this to your proguard rules file:

`-keep class com.cloudinary.** { *; }`

Comment: Even though this will solve the issue, it's not the right answer because it keeps all the classes in the SDK which is the complete opposite of the purpose of proguard and any other shrinker.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this issue:

`-keep class * extends com.cloudinary.strategies.*`

this will only keep the missing classes that the SDK needs and mentioned in this error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add http cloud library,you can find at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cloudinary/cloudinary-http44/1.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.24.1 of the sdk, this issue is fixed as the sdk add the proguard rules itself. See commit https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_android/commit/c8ce933d4396867a18aeb1511198f2abad065e95